# Plotting with NDSolve Dividing by the Solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Why do we have to divide by the solution when plotting the results from NDsolve?

For example, given

```
ode1 = {y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == 2, y'[0] == 1};
sol = NDSolve[ode1, y, {x, -10, 10}]
```

Then the following plots the solution.

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, -10, 10}]
```

Why must we include `/.sol`? What are we actually dividing by?

Comment: See [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

Comment: See also http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html

Comment: And finally, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706